# c# continue code in try even if it catches exception

Tags: c#, try-catch

I created an email app, which sends email to all users in database, but I have a problem, where if users email is invalid, try catch shows an exception and stop sending letters to others. Heres my try catch code

```
try
{
    foreach (string item in risto)
    {
        AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(txtBEmail.Text, item, txtBTema.Text, rtxtBContent.Text);
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);
        // SmtpServer = smtp.company.com; Ex: Gmail - smtp.gmail.com | Yahoo - smtp.yahoo.com
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.mailExample.com");
        client.Port = 587;


        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtBEmail.Text, txtBPass.Text);
        client.EnableSsl = false;
        client.Send(mail);
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Sent", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    txtBEmail.Text = "";
    txtBPass.Text = "";
    txtBTema.Text = "";
    txtBPic.Text = "";
    txtBLink.Text = "";
    rtxtBContent.Text = "";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Bad data" + ex);
    txtBEmail.Text = "";
    txtBPass.Text = "";
    txtBTema.Text = "";
    txtBPic.Text = "";
    txtBLink.Text = "";
    rtxtBContent.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Put the foreach around the `try{} catch(){}`. The execution inside the try catch always breaks if an exception occurs, jumps into the catch and then leaves the try catch block (except if a finally statement is defined, if so this is executed last before leaving the block).

Comment: or put try-catch inside foreach :).

Comment: @SeM Not sure if this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a separate try/catch for each email:

```
foreach (var mail in emails)
{
    bool emailSent;
    // Prepare single email here

    try
    {
        // Try do send it here
        // ....
        client.Send(mail);
        // If the code comes here, it means the mail was sent
        emailSent = true;
    }
    catch 
    {
        // log the exception
    }

    Debug.WriteLine($"Email to {mail} status: {emailSent}");
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I can't believe it was that simple, unfortunately im not that good at programming yet, thank you for your time

Comment: This will also stop sending mails if one fails, except for the last I guess. Using a catch without throwing the exception should be the solution here.

Comment: @Silvermind you're 100% right, thanks for noticing, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You have your `try`/`catch` construct around the *entire loop*. That means once one message fails, control moves to the catch block and the loop stops.

You need to put the `try`/`catch` *inside* the loop to catch *each* possible exception and to be able to continue your loop with the next item.